# Android - UX design conventions concerning "Cancel" and "Done" buttons

Tags: android, user-experience

I am new to Android and I am creating an app in which you have a form which you can save similar to how it is done in the contacts app.

My question is: how should I display "Cancel" and "Done" buttons? Should I even display a "Cancel" button in the first place, since the hardware back button (or the action bar's up-navigation) should suffice?

The screenshot below shows how it is done in the Contacts app, but I am wondering if this is "the way to go", because this way the buttons take a lot of screen space for no reason. On iPhone you have a small "Done" button on the top right (inside the navigation bar / action bar). I tend to do the same for this Android app, but I don't want to do anything that users don't expect.

[image: Cancel and Done buttons in the Android Contacts app]

So can someone please help me out here? :)

Comment: Use the dedicated site http://ux.stackexchange.com/ , your question is offtopic here.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not realise there was a separate site for these kinds of questions. I will re-create the question over there.

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49504/android-ux-design-conventions-concerning-cancel-and-done-buttons

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, put the "Done" in a [contextual action bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html).

Back does not work as "Cancel" - it should also persist whatever edits made so far.

(Buttons like "Done" and "Cancel" are valid in an alert dialog but that is not the case here.)

Comment: Back persists all edits? This one is new to me. Can you point me towards some apps that do this? And if that's the case, why have a "Done" button in the first place?

Comment: For example, the built-in Contacts app in this KitKat device in front of me.